# Cannot Install Bower - Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, syntax

First off, I am a complete novice. I have just started learning programming today and I am trying to learn jQuery. But in order to use jQuery I have had to get bower and npm (node), which has been a confusing ordeal. So I downloaded node:

Node was installed at

/usr/local/bin/node

npm was installed at

/usr/local/bin/npm

Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

Then I read:
Install Bower globally using NPM.

npm install -g bower

Which I tried doing in Chrome with Javascript. Then I read on this site that appropriate syntax is:
$ npm config set prefix /usr/local
$ npm install -g bower

I have tried a bunch of others too, all the same error
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

So I'm a newbie that needs some expert guidance on this trivial programming because I am making a mistake somewhere and I have no idea what it is I am doing wrong.

Comment: If you just started learning programming today, NodeJS is not a good option because it's very low level language

Comment: @ShamalSandeep — Wha? Node is means to run JavaScript. It's a *very* high level language.

Comment: @Quentin When you work with scalable network applications nodejs is not so good for beginners

Comment: Why would beginners be dealing with scalable network applications?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message indicates that you are typing your `npm` command at a JavaScript prompt. It is not a JavaScript function, it is a separate program. Type it at your normal (e.g. `bash`) command prompt.

That said, you do not need to go anywhere near Node.js in order to use jQuery. It is most commonly used inside a webpage, not in a Node.js application. See the [getting started guide](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/getting-started/) on the jQuery website.

Comment: I understand the first two sentences, but you lose me on the third. I don't know what a 'bash' command prompt is.   I think I failed to mention earlier I am using a mac, not sure if that makes any difference

Comment: Being on a Mac makes it easier (since it comes with bash, just run the Terminal program), but the important bit is the second paragraph.